# Error while implementing a StringListModel from QAbstractListModel in Pyqt

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt4

The purpose of this code is to show a list of string with a model herited from `QtCore.QAbstractListModel`

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class StringListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, strings):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self)
        self._string_list = strings
    def rowCount(self):
        return len(self._string_list)
    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid() : return QtCore.QVariant()
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole : return QtCore.QVariant()
        if index.row() <= self.rowCount() : return QtCore.QVariant()
        return QtCore.QVariant(self._string_list[index.row()])
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role != QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole : return QtCore.QVariant()
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal : return QtCore.QVariant("Column %s"%section)
        else:
            return QtCore.QVariant("Row %s"%section)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    lines = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
    model = StringListModel(lines)
    view = QtGui.QListView()
    view.setModel(model)
    view.setWindowTitle("String list model")
    view.show()
    a.exec_()
```

The error I've got is

> TypeError: rowCount() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that QAbstractItemModel.rowCount takes a 'parent' parameter. The following tweak suppresses the error (though I don't know if it actually implements the correct logic)

```
def rowCount(self, parent=None):
    return len(self._string_list)
```

Also, are you sure that QListWidget doesn't provide the functionality you need?

Comment: Thanks, but now I have another error: TypeError: PyQt4.QtCore.QVariant represents a mapped type and cannot be instantiated . IS the QVariant unappropriated type for this?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382025/qvariant-in-qcombobox-python-2-vs-python-3 . The punchline is that there are two ways of using PyQt4 -- one where QVariant is used directly, and one where you use normal python objects instead. You seem to be set up to use the newer version where QVariant isn't used directly. Try using direct python objects instead of QVariants. (if it doesn't work, you probably want to post as a new question)